# ACCESS: Ticking checkbox on form if a value beginning with "(REF)" is selected from combobox

Tags: forms, ms-access, if-statement, checkbox, sql-like

I am trying to tick a check box on a form when I select one of many combobox values that begins with (REF)  - this is code that stands for Referral closure.

this is what I've done..it's not working

```
Private Sub ReasonForInappriopriateReferral_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.RsnForInappropriateRef.Value Like "(REF)*" Then
        Me.Check66 = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help, I was previously trying to conditional format a label to a different colour if the closure reason was a Referral closure, but couldn't do that either and think it could be down to the IF Like command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two controls exactly as you indicated.  I populated my combo by setting the Row Source Type to a Value List, and the Row Source to "Blah Blah";"(REF) - Jackson";"Two Times";"(REF) - Tyson"

I put this in the Click event of a button:

```
If Me.RsnForInappropriateRef.Value Like "(REF)*" Then
    Me.Check66 = True
Else
    Me.Check66 = False
End If
```

it behaved exactly as expected.  I then moved it to the AfterUpdate event of the combobox, and again it worked flawlessly.  The only thing I can see is that in your example, the combobox does not have the same name as your sub (ReasonForInappriopriateReferral vs RsnForInappropriateRef).  Are you sure your names are right?

Comment: Hi, I know its been a while since the question, thank you for your answer I have only be able to look at this today - Your right it must be the names so I will have a go today, Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: I am a complete plonker and forgot that the combo box is linked from another table with a PrimaryKey to allow the manager to edit the catergories to the dropdown with ease - and the the combobox on the form was bound to the primarykey instead of the clousure describtion. - It took a while I got there in the end

Comment: Here's the finished code that worked for future ref:If Me.Ref.Column(1) Like "(REF)*" Then

   Me.tickRefClosure = True
       
   Else

   Me.tickRefClosure = False

End If